# Stop accessing my domain using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've multiple domain hosting account and so I've hosted multiple domains on that. So I want to separate those with the main domain.

```
Main hosting : https://example.com
Other hosted website : https://mydomain1.com, https://mydomain2.com
```

Other hosted websites are under path

```
https://example.com/domains/mydomain1
https://example.com/domains/mydomain2
```

So anyone can access the other domain using the above mentioned paths(if he knows)
So to separate all domains I want if anyone accessing the domains using the path it should display error message like 404 or 403

But I don't want anyone to access using such path instead he/she can use the actual domain name to access.

Any suggestion appreciated.

PS: I've htaccess file in my other domain to redirect http request to https

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Is there any other way to achieve both. redirection to https and above query.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `mydomain1/.htaccess` and `mydomain2/.htaccess` have this rule as your very first rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

# show forbidden for main domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: let me give a try

Comment: can we put the htaccess file inside 'domains' folder, it will work for all domains i guess

Comment: It is not working because in my other domains there is htaccess file where i'm redirecting http request to https, :( sad. How to tackle two htaccess

Comment: I'm not sure about apache version, how to check?

Comment: Is it possible to ignore the child htaccess completely? Because my child also have ErrorDocument 403 handle, so parent ErrorDocument handle is not working correctly. If I remove the child 403 handle, it is working perfectly. but Child 403 handle is also important for that domain.

Comment: For `404` change `[F]` to `[L,R=404]`. You cannot stop child .htaccess directives. May be you can try `RewriteOptions Inherit` which will overwrite child directives by parent directives.

Comment: I did the 404 thing already :) but thank you for that, and your suggestions worked. thank you so much.

Comment: I need to learn more about htaccess, its seems little difficult but its pretty good.