# How to allow htaccess to perform only if the request is from the particular domain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've multiple domain hosting account, so we all must know that other domain can be access through the main domain as I've stated in my earlier [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48539144/stop-accessing-my-domain-using-htaccess/)

As per the answer I'm having few issues related to subdomains and other `htaccess` in sub folder

**So I'm just wondering if I can perform `htaccess` queries only if the request is coming from the particular domain say *example.com***

for example :

```
if request is from example.com then
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
else
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
end if
```

Something like this. Above statements are only example.

I searched for this but no result what I want. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I can’t see what sense your example is supposed to make. Even if there was such an if/else available, you are doing the exact same rewriting in both cases - only that in one you try to enable the rewrite engine before, and in the other you don’t. What’s the reasoning behind that?

Comment: Also, what exactly do you mean by “request coming from” here? Do you mean the user should have reached the subdomain by following a link on your main domain?

Comment: If you go through my linked question you will come to know. In Short, domain1.com is hosted is hosted on example.com server (multiple domain hosting) so domain1 can be access through example.com/domain1, what i dont want. So, if anyone accessing example.com/domain1 it should block the access and return 404. but sub domain htaccess giving me problem.

Comment: I hope you understand, I've explained in detail in the linked question. Pardon if have not able to see linked question.

Comment: You already accepted the answer you got on that question, so what exactly is different now? And you still have not explained what “request coming from domain” is supposed to mean. Requests don’t come “from domains”, they come from clients, such as a browser.

Comment: let me update my question

Answer (score 0):

You can check the referrer, but note that this information is not very reliable as it is provided by the visitor and can be manipulated:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# Add the referrer as a condition for this rewrite rule
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: `RewriteEngine On` is giving me problem as parent htaccess also having `RewriteEngine On` so my child htaccess invalidating the parent htaccess. I want if the conditon is true then only `RewriteRule` should perform else no. Because I can have multiple `RewriteRule`. Sorry I'm begginner in htaccess. :(

Comment: @AmitSingh The `RewriteEngine On` part is not part of this rule, that's why I separated it from the rest. This rule consists of just 2 conditions and the rewrite rule.